# Apple Headers contain multiple Categories

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, categories

While perusing some Apple Header files, I notice that they declare multiple interfaces using Categories for the same object.

For example: `NSDictionary.h`

```
@interface NSDictionary : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSCoding, NSFastEnumeration>

//methods

@end

@interface NSDictionary (NSExtendedDictionary)

//methods

@end

@interface NSDictionary (NSDictionaryCreation)

//methods

@end
```

Is this purely a way to help organize the code? As a user there is no difference, all methods in all Categories appear when utilizing a `NSDictionary`.

Is there some other useful result of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nielsbot has the right idea, but there's a specific technical reason for the categories.  You can put the implementations in separate files.  (Well, different *translation units* technically speaking.)

**File 1:**

```
@implementation NSDictionary
...
@end
```

**File 2:**

```
@implementation NSDictionary (NSExtendedDictionary)
...
@end
```

**File 3:**

```
@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionaryCreation)
...
@end
```

Comment: @Bavarious Just to summarize, in that case: it’s worth mentioning that you’ll get a warning if you declare a category, then write an `@implementation` section that doesn’t implement all the methods you declared.  There’s nothing wrong with having categories that don’t have `@implementation` sections, however; historically you might have used such categories on e.g. `NSObject` as a means of creating an _informal protocol_, but Apple now uses and recommends `@protocol` with the `@optional` keyword instead.

Comment: also vice-versa: you can write an @implementation for a category without creating the @interface portion. I do this all the time for private add-ons to existing classes. Again--it's a good way to organize your code.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it's an organization thing. I am not aware of any other benefit of using Categories in a public header file. (They are of course useful for inserting new methods into existing classes)

EDIT:
Check out Wikipedia. They seem to have a pretty authoritative answer:

During the design of Objective-C, one of the main concerns was the maintainability of large code bases. Experience from the structured programming world had shown that one of the main ways to improve code was to break it down into smaller pieces. Objective-C borrowed and extended the concept of categories from Smalltalk implementations to help with this process.[9]

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories

Seems to fit as well since the system headers came from NeXT--those are the guys that would write code in this fashion.

Comment: Also, container classes like NSDictionary and NSArray have multiple backing data structures based on metrics like size, so organization in this way works especially well, since you can separate out methods by the data structure they operate on.

Comment: I'm not so sure that wikipedia reference really explains it - I think it's talking more to creating a base class like 'NSDictionary' and then using a category to extend it without going through subclassing or other things that would result in creating bigger pieces.  That was my reading anyway